# I can not take all the arrays for serialize jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that has three checkbox lists, the three are dynamically generated
what I want and that as the User is clicking the checkbox values ​​are passed via post, but I only managed to catch Esto values ​​of the first list
I did the code like this:

```
         $("body").find(".fcID").click(function(){
//  var v = $(this).val();
    //alert(v);
    var form = jQuery('#form');     
    valor = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url:"biblioteca/filtra.php",
        data: valor,

        success: function(data){
            $("#tabelafiltro").html(data);
        }
    });
```

in html, I put a form with the id of her form and name the form
within that form, I have the checkboxes, so:

```
     <form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">

<table>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="fcID" value="<?php echo $linha['fm-cod-com'] ?>"   name="fcID[]"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="fcID" name="fam[]" value="<?php echo $linha['fm-codigo'] ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

and the php:

```
    $id = $_POST['fcID'];
$fam = $_POST['fam'];

echo(count($fam)) . " + " . count($id);
```

somebody help me?

Comment: have you tried console.log(valor) to see what data are you acctually sending?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, are u sure that the fam[] checkboxes are checked? Checkboxes will serialize only if they have atribute checked="checked".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "name" is not converted to an array by jQuery.. so instead of this:

```
echo $_POST['fcID'][0]; // undefined
```

you have this

```
echo $_POST['fcID[]']; // expected value
```

I created the following. It has some limitations, but should do what you want. I appreciate if you can rate my answer.

```
var form = jQuery('#form');     
valor = form.formToObj();

// formToObj (c) 2012 Frank Forte.
// Please contact me for a free license to use on personal or business website
// @frankforte or frank @ interactinet .com!
jQuery.fn.formToObj = function()
{
    var obj = {}
    jQuery("input,select,textarea",this).each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).attr("disabled")){
            return;
        }

        var n = jQuery(this).attr("name") || jQuery(this).attr("id")
        var v = jQuery(this).val();
        // e.g.<input name="test[one][two][three]" value="hello world">

        if(!n.match(/\[/))
        {
            obj[n] = v
        }
        else
        {
            // get keys of array, e.g. "one","two","three"
            var keys = []
            nkeys= n.split('[')
            var i = 0;
            for(k in nkeys)
            {
                if(i > 0)
                {
                    var nk = nkeys[k]
                    if(typeof nk == "string")
                    {
                        if(nk.match(/\]/))
                        {
                            nk = nk.replace("]","")
                        }
                        keys.push(nk);
                    }
                }
                i++
            }
            // name e.g. "test"
            n = n.replace(/^([^\[\]]+)\[.*$/i,"$1");

            // create object and add value then array keys from bottom up
            var iobj = {}
            for(i = keys.length; i > 0; i--)
            {
                j = i-1;
                var k = keys[j]
                if(k==""){k = 0;}

                if(i == keys.length)
                {
                    iobj[k] = v
                }
                else
                {
                    iobj[k] = iobj
                }
            }
            // Need to start with obj[n] and add new values under appropriate keys
            // prevents unsetting or overwriting keys deeper than n
            if(typeof obj[n] == "undefined")
            {
                obj[n] = {}
            }
            obj[n][k] = iobj[k]
        }
    })
    return obj
}
```